# 18.04 Bluetooth Crashing

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, 18.04, crash

Hello I have a Dell Precision 5520 (purchased February, 2018) with the Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter running Ubuntu 18.04.

I am having trouble with the bluetooth connection between the laptop and my Logitech MX Master wireless mouse. The computer will lose connection with the mouse multiple times per day. When this happens, the bluetooth icon in the upper right-hand corner of the screen disappears. Checking the Bluetooth system preference panel, Bluetooth is turned off. I can toggle the switch to "on" but bluetooth remains off. Neither restarting the computer nor power cycling the computer bring bluetooth back. `$ sudo service bluetooth restart` also doesn't work. The only way I have found to renable bluetooth is:

1. reboot
2. disable bluetooth in BIOS
3. reboot
4. enable bluetooth in BIOS
5. reboot

Also, I was running Ubuntu 16.04 until this past Friday. I experienced this problem under 16.04 but it happened much less frequently (once every couple weeks or so). I upgraded to 18.04 ahead of 18.04.1 in hopes that a newer kernel/driver would work better with my brand new hardware. Now, under 18.04, bluetooth is crashing multiple times per day.

Here is the output of `$ grep blue /var/log/syslog` immediately after bluetooth crashed.

```
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:dev_class_changed_callback() Class: 0x000000
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:new_settings_callback() Settings: 0x00000ada
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:settings_changed() Changed settings: 0x00000001
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:cancel_passive_scanning()
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove_connection()
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_stop() adapter /org/bluez/hci0 has been disabled
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/device.c:att_disconnected_cb()
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/device.c:att_disconnected_cb() Software caused connection abort (103)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278ad2320: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile batt-profile state changed: connected -> disconnecting (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278ad2320: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile batt-profile state changed: disconnecting -> disconnected (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278ad2230: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile deviceinfo state changed: connected -> disconnecting (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278ad2230: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile deviceinfo state changed: disconnecting -> disconnected (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278adce30: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile gap-profile state changed: connected -> disconnecting (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278adce30: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile gap-profile state changed: disconnecting -> disconnected (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278adc150: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile input-hog state changed: connected -> disconnecting (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: attrib/gattrib.c:g_attrib_unref() 0x565278add490: g_attrib_unref=1
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278adc150: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile input-hog state changed: disconnecting -> disconnected (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:btd_gatt_client_disconnected() Device disconnected. Cleaning up.
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: attrib/gattrib.c:g_attrib_unref() 0x565278add490: g_attrib_unref=0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:index_removed() index 0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_unregister() Unregister path: /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_remove() Removing adapter /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/device.c:device_remove() Removing device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278ad2320: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile batt-profile state changed: disconnected -> unavailable (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/battery/battery.c:batt_remove() BATT profile remove (F9:9B:77:D9:08:61)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:btd_service_unref() 0x565278ad2320: ref=0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278ad2230: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile deviceinfo state changed: disconnected -> unavailable (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:btd_service_unref() 0x565278ad2230: ref=0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278adce30: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile gap-profile state changed: disconnected -> unavailable (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/gap/gas.c:gap_remove() GAP profile remove (F9:9B:77:D9:08:61)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:btd_service_unref() 0x565278adce30: ref=0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:change_state() 0x565278adc150: device F9:9B:77:D9:08:61 profile input-hog state changed: disconnected -> unavailable (0)
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:btd_service_unref() 0x565278adc150: ref=1
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/input/hog.c:hog_remove() path /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/service.c:btd_service_unref() 0x565278adc150: ref=0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/device.c:btd_device_unref() Freeing device /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_service() Removing GATT service: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service0008
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_characteristic() Removing GATT characteristic: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service0008/char0009
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_descriptor() Removing GATT descriptor: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service0008/char0009/desc000b
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_service() Removing GATT service: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service000c
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_characteristic() Removing GATT characteristic: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service000c/char000d
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_characteristic() Removing GATT characteristic: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service000c/char000f
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_characteristic() Removing GATT characteristic: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service000c/char0011
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_characteristic() Removing GATT characteristic: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service000c/char0013
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_characteristic() Removing GATT characteristic: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service000c/char0015
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_characteristic() Removing GATT characteristic: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service000c/char0017
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_characteristic() Removing GATT characteristic: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service000c/char0019
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_service() Removing GATT service: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service003f
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_characteristic() Removing GATT characteristic: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service003f/char0040
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/gatt-client.c:unregister_descriptor() Removing GATT descriptor: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_F9_9B_77_D9_08_61/service003f/char0040/desc0042
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/device.c:device_free() 0x565278adc490
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: plugins/hostname.c:hostname_remove()
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:media_server_remove() path /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/media.c:release_endpoint() sender=:1.452 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_service_remove() /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:remove_uuid() sending remove uuid command for index 0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/sdpd-service.c:remove_record_from_server() Removing record with handle 0x10003
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/media.c:release_endpoint() sender=:1.452 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.452 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/media.c:media_endpoint_destroy() sender=:1.452 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_unregister_sep() SEP 0x565278ade790 unregistered: type:0 codec:0 seid:1
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/media.c:release_endpoint() sender=:1.452 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_service_remove() /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:remove_uuid() sending remove uuid command for index 0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/sdpd-service.c:remove_record_from_server() Removing record with handle 0x10004
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/media.c:release_endpoint() sender=:1.452 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.452 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/media.c:media_endpoint_destroy() sender=:1.452 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_unregister_sep() SEP 0x565278ae1c90 unregistered: type:1 codec:0 seid:2
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/profile.c:ext_adapter_remove() "Headset Voice gateway" removed
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_service_remove() /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:remove_uuid() sending remove uuid command for index 0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/sdpd-service.c:remove_record_from_server() Removing record with handle 0x10005
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:a2dp_source_server_remove() path /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/a2dp.c:a2dp_sink_server_remove() path /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/avrcp.c:avrcp_target_server_remove() path /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_service_remove() /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:remove_uuid() sending remove uuid command for index 0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/sdpd-service.c:remove_record_from_server() Removing record with handle 0x10002
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/audio/avrcp.c:avrcp_controller_server_remove() path /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_service_remove() /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:remove_uuid() sending remove uuid command for index 0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/sdpd-service.c:remove_record_from_server() Removing record with handle 0x10001
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/network/manager.c:nap_server_remove() path /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/network/manager.c:gn_server_remove() path /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/network/manager.c:panu_server_remove() path /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: profiles/network/server.c:path_unregister() Unregistered interface org.bluez.NetworkServer1 on path /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:btd_adapter_unref() Freeing adapter /org/bluez/hci0
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/adapter.c:adapter_free() 0x565278acdb00
Jun  6 09:12:41 Precision-5520 bluetoothd[3189]: src/rfkill.c:rfkill_event() RFKILL event idx 9 type 2 op 1 soft 0 hard 0
Jun  6 09:12:42 Precision-5520 systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
```

I'm new to Ubuntu and not sure where to turn next. Any insight or help would be appreciated. This is rapidly getting annoying! Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a kernel bug. Report it to Launchpad.

Comment: Done, thanks! https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1775443

Comment: There is no debug information. The report will be closed. Run `apport-collect 1775443`

Comment: Ran that, connected to the Launchpad account, and got "No additional information collected."

Comment: The problem is that you've chosen a wrong module. The correct was `ubuntu-bug linux`, not `linux-signed`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I don't recall choosing `linux-signed`, though I see that in the bug report. How do I choose the correct module?

Comment: Try now. I added `linux` there. It looks like I have some privileges there ;-)

Comment: And also add the log there instead of a link to this question.

Comment: You got it. Thanks for your help. Really nice to have someone with experience help the new guy!

Answer (score 0):

i had on ubuntu 16.04 sometimes bluetooth problems, which i solved with an other app

```
sudo apt install blueman
```

so i got my blutooth connection problems mostly solved, and the handling of multiple blutooth adapters is configurable.

so i am no hardware specialist.